# How to perform filtered arithmetic between rows in a data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

I have a (tidy) data frame that looks like so:

```
!> my_table
 # A tibble: 8 × 4
            g     a     b     val
       <date> <lgl> <lgl>   <int>
 1 2015-01-01 FALSE FALSE 3175030
 2 2015-01-01 FALSE  TRUE   72229
 3 2015-01-01  TRUE FALSE  125505
 4 2015-01-01  TRUE  TRUE  856737
 5 2015-02-01 FALSE FALSE 3413510
 6 2015-02-01 FALSE  TRUE   69203
 7 2015-02-01  TRUE FALSE  122925
 8 2015-02-01  TRUE  TRUE  876366
```

Now I'd like to group-by `g` and perform arithmetic *between rows* based on filters on columns `a` and `b`.
For example, I'd like to take (for each group) the difference between the `(TRUE,FALSE)` row and the `(FALSE,TRUE)` row:

```
 # A tibble: 2 × 2
            g  diff
       <date> <int>
 1 2015-01-01 53276
 2 2015-02-01 53722
```

In a non/semi-tidyverse-world, I'd do something like filter first on the `(TRUE,FALSE)` rows then join that with another filtered table on the `(FALSE,TRUE)` rows, then take the difference between the `c` columns for each, like so:

```
diff_table <- inner_join(
  filter(my_table, a, !b) %>% select(g, val1 = val),
 ,filter(my_table, !a, b) %>% select(g, val2 = val)
) %>% transmute(g, diff = val1 - val2)
```

This works just fine...
but seems inelegant and I think I might be missing an easier method by which this can be done using `group_by`.
I.e. grouping by `g` then performing arithmetic on specific values on/between rows.
Anyone know of a more 'tidy' and elegant solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
df %>% 
  group_by(g) %>%
  filter(a + b == 1) %>%
  arrange(a) %>%
  summarise(diff=diff(val))

# A tibble: 2 × 2
           g  diff
      <date> <int>
1 2015-01-01 53276
2 2015-02-01 53722
```

Comment: Yes and no... that works for this instance, but the filtering variables (`a` and `b`) might not always be so easily treated as logical/integers as in this case. Imagine a third filtering variable as a factor that qualifies rows based on a subset of possible levels...

Comment: Would you like to provide some examples?